# Probability for drawing balls in a monotonic (increasing and decreasing) order with order and without replacement

Tags: probability, permutations

Having an urn with 7 balls each having printed its numbers 1 - 7 on it, we draw 4 of them without replacement and order matters. I am trying to find the probability of drawing them in a monotonic order (decreasing and increasing).

- I think it should be possible to count the increasing in this case and assume that the decreasing case is symmetrically the same. Even though counting leads to a solution I want to know if there is a smarter way to derive the value of the nominator for even bigger values.
- My first guess at this was coming up with $n \choose k$ $= {7 \choose 4}$, since it counts the number of all strictly monotonic mappings $[k] \rightarrow [n]$
- The denominator should be $n! \over (n-k)!$ $= 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$

Thus,  $\Pr = 2 \frac{{7 \choose 4}}{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4} = {1 \over 12}$

Is this interpretation correct or might ${1 \over 12}$ be too likely for being true? I am also wondering if $n \choose k$ can even be applied since we have order without replacement.

Comment: There are $4!=24$ possible orders of the balls, and $2$ of them are monotonic.  (Not "monotonous", please.  That means "boring".)  So yes, the probability is $\frac1{12}$

Comment: @saulspatz You beat me to it. That is one method of taking the mystery out of some order problems.

Comment: Edited, sorry for my poor English. Wow, that was a short explanation, thanks!